# Complex or several simple models must be used?

Tags: machine-learning

I can't understand how models may be organised.

I want try create some algorithms which helps analyze product name (description) and gets product properties (category, some parameters).

I have tree structured data:

```
Category (name, null parent)
  |Category (name, parent)
    |Product (name+description)
      |Param(key-value)
      |Param(key-value)
      |Param(key-value)
      |...
```

I use model which will clasify top category for product, and after I use an other model which is trained on products which are belongs to the classified top category (so I can classify second level category). 
For next step I use own models for every `param key` for `param value` classification

In general, do I need a model for every leaf of my `tree structure` for next classification step?

Are my thoughts right?

Answer (score 1):

That's one way of proceeding. However I seed 2 problem of in the approach:

First, you segment training data and the final classifiers may not have enough data to be trained.

Second, I guess that the Param Key-Value can be repeated across different categories and products. So you are training different classifiers for the same things on different products and categories may not be a good idea because of the training data segmentation.

It is to have a classifier for the categories and one classifier for the products. But having a classifier for each property may be too much. I would recommend you to take a look into **multi class classification**. These algorithms can handle several classes for each input. So you could use them to model all the  Param Key-Value

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

And if you really have a huge amount of leafs then you can try **Extreme Multi Label**

> "extreme multi label learning text classification"

Comment: After analyze the dataset I can say "parameter keys are strongly related to categories" (only few params may be in the different categories, so I can consider they are different params for simplify the task).

Comment: Then you may have 1 multi label model for each category. This model will classify all the Param Key-Values for the category

Comment: Yes you are right. I can use flat multi label for all categories (without nesting), but  what about accuracy (it is easier for a person to choose from a smaller number of values)? The same question about flat Param Key-Value classification (for each category)...

Comment: If I will use flat big classifier for Param Key-Value I will need some score for "match check" (not simple "head" for by key classification)

Comment: The multi label classifiers should be as good as having single classifiers, but saving a lot of space and memory instead. For the scoring, most multi-label problems evaluate on a match score, however you can easily compute accuracy on multi label schemes

Comment: What about different models by parameter key if it's better to have product names prepared in different ways (n-grams or words). For some keys we have true/false value and in text we may have "not"/"none" additions.